# How to offer a discount

Tags: cognito-forms

I'd like to add the opposite of "Additional Fees" in the Payment Settings; basically, I want to offer a discount of 5% for 20 to 40€ items purchased, 10% for 40 to 80€ and 15% off for more than 80€ purchased.

Is that possible?

Comment: Check [this help page](http://blog.cognitoforms.com/3-easy-ways-to-create-discounts-on-payment-forms) — it’s exactly what you are looking for (under **Volume Discounts**).

Answer (score 2):

Applying discounts in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com) is both easy and powerful.  The key is to use the Price field to calculate negative prices based on form selections.

To start with, check out this great blog post describing [three easy ways to create discounts on payment forms](http://blog.cognitoforms.com/3-easy-ways-to-create-discounts-on-payment-forms).  Then use a calculation like the following to apply your discount via the [Price field](http://help.cognitoforms.com/price-field):

```
=if TotalBeforeDiscount > 80 then -0.15 * TotalBeforeDiscount else
 if TotalBeforeDiscount > 40 then -0.10 * TotalBeforeDiscount else
 if TotalBeforeDiscount > 20 then -0.05 * TotalBeforeDiscount else 0
```

In this case, `TotalBeforeDiscount` is a Calculation field that you create to subtotal the form prior to applying the discount.